# WKWebView ViewportSizing logs in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In using [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/), the [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) loads successfully when implemented within a [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) wrapper. However, the following logs appear in the Debug area of [Xcode Version 13.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_4_1-release-notes):

```
[ViewportSizing] maximumViewportInset cannot be larger than frame
[ViewportSizing] minimumViewportInset cannot be larger than frame
```

How can these logs be resolved?

These logs can be reproduced with the following minimal reproducible example:

WebApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

@main
struct WebApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            WebView()
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
        
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {}
}
```

PROGRESS:

These logs seem to originate from the following WebKit browser engine source code:

- maximumViewportInset: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/main/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebView.mm#L1623
- minimumViewportInset: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/main/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebView.mm#L1638

These logs persist despite commenting out the `webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))` line. So, it's concludable that it's not a website issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be resolved by setting the frame to more than zero by changing this:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
```

To this:

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.1, height: 0.1))
```